# "double free or corruption" error when implementing Dynamic Array Data Structure

Tags: c++, memory-management, destructor, dynamic-arrays

I am trying to implement a dynamic array data structure for my data structures and algorithms course, but I think I am having some troubles with memory management. My template class is as follows.

**ArrayList.h**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
using namespace std;
#define Length(array) (sizeof((array))/sizeof((array[0])))

template <class T>
class ArrayList
{
    public:

    ArrayList() {a = new T[1]; n = 0;}
    ~ArrayList() {delete [] a;}

    int size();
    int backingSize();
    T get(int i);
    T set(int i, T x);
    void add(int i, T x);
    T remove (int i);

    private:

    void resize();

    T *a;
    int n;
};

template <class T>
int ArrayList<T>::size() { return n; }

template <class T>
int ArrayList<T>::backingSize() { return Length(a); }

template <class T>
T ArrayList<T>::get(int i) { return a[i]; }

template <class T>
T ArrayList<T>::set(int i, T x) 
{ 
    T temp = a[i];
    a[i] = x;
    return temp;
}

template <class T>
void ArrayList<T>::add(int i, T x) 
{
    if (n+1 > Length(a)) resize();
    for (int j = n; j > i; j--) a[j] = a[j-1];
    a[i] = x;
    n++;
}

template <class T>
T ArrayList<T>::remove(int i) 
{
    T temp = a[i];
    for (int j = i; j < n-1; j++) a[j] = a[j+1];
    n--; 
    if (Length(a) > 3*n) resize();
    return temp; 
}

template <class T>
void ArrayList<T>::resize() 
{
    if ( n+1 > Length(a))
    {
        cout << "Making Bigger\n"; 
        T* tempArr = new T[2*n];
        memcpy(tempArr, a, n * sizeof(T));
        delete [] a;
        a = tempArr;
    }

    else   //  (Length(a) > 3*n)
    {
        cout << "Making Smaller\n";
        T* tempArr = new T[n/2];
        memcpy(tempArr, a, n * sizeof(T));
        delete [] a;
        a = tempArr;
    }
}
```

I then test it with the following main function

**TestArrayList.cpp**

```
#include "ArrayList.h"
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    ArrayList <int> myList;

    cout << myList.size() << "\n\n";

    myList.add(0,15);
    cout << myList.get(0) << ", " << myList.size() << ", " << myList.backingSize() << "\n";
    myList.add(1,34);
    cout << myList.get(1) << ", " << myList.size() << ", " << myList.backingSize() << "\n";
    myList.add(2,23);
    cout << myList.get(2) << ", " << myList.size() << ", " << myList.backingSize() << "\n";
    myList.add(3,1);
    cout << myList.get(3) << ", " << myList.size() << ", " << myList.backingSize() << "\n\n";

    myList.~ArrayList();
}
```

The code compiles and runs with the following output to the terminal:

```
15, 1, 2
34, 2, 2
Making Bigger
23, 3, 2
Making Bigger
1, 4, 2

*** Error in `./TestArrayList': double free or corruption (fasttop): 0x000000000090c010 ***
Aborted
```

It seems to be working as expected, the get function returns the proper values at their indexes, the size function returns the proper length of the array and their are no seg faults. But, the `backingSize()` function always returns 2 and the error thrown at the end that I assume has something to do with bad memory management. I have been stumped for quite a while so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You should also define a copy constructor, assignment operator and move assignment operator for your type (or delete them)

Comment: What about stepping through with the debugger 1st, to determine where you could possibly hit the `delete []` twice?

Comment: Don't call destructor explicitly - it will be automatically called when the variable leaves scope.

Comment: `memcpy(tempArr, a, n * sizeof(T));`  This will not work correctly if `T` is a non-POD type.  For example, if `T` is a `std::string`, this code leads to undefined behavior.  There is so much wrong with your code, it goes beyond learning "data structures and algorithms".  C++ just isn't cut out for learning plain old "data structures and algorithms" unless you know all the nuances of the language.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You explicitly call the destructor of the object. The destructor is called automatically, so due to the fact that you already called it, a double free error occurs.

To understand when the destructor is called, have a look at this [link](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/destructor)

Answer (score 1):

Here is a bug(not sure if there are no others):

```
T* tempArr = new T[n / 2]; // the size is n / 2
memcpy(tempArr, a, n * sizeof(T)); // but here you try to copy n elements
```

`tempArr` can hold only `n / 2` elements, but you try to copy `n` elements into it. It is undefined behavior. Moreover, it is not feasible to copy elements byte by byte for all possible types `T`.

Comment: For the first one, I meant it to be the length of the backing array over two. Thanks. I am not sure I fully understand your second part though. Are you saying memcpy() cannot be used for all types, but it works in my case because I am testing with ints?

Comment: @jasper it works for `int` because `int` is trivially copyable.

Answer (score 0):

You should never use `#define Length(array) (sizeof((array))/sizeof((array[0])))` on pointers.  There is no way to know the size of an array from a pointer.  This is probably leading to your issues.  Since you have a class why not just store the size and capacity as variables?  when dealing with array type objects the 8 bytes the size and capacity take up in memory is really nothing.